# How to convert float value to int while updating in MongoDB Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to update a field which will be the product of a field and a number. the result is coming as a float in the db but I want it to be an integer. How do I do it?

```
final Bson update = set("percent_view", new BasicDBObject("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$viewtime", percent)));
```

Comment: You'd be better off leaving it like that and *presenting* it as an integral value. There's never a good reason for diminishing precision in your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **use** the `$toInt` aggregation operator to convert the `floating-point` result to an `integer` before updating the field

Here is the sample code shown below

```
Bson update = Updates.set("percent_view", new Document("$toInt", new Document("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$viewtime", percent))));
```